# How to get the Y position of a node1 relative the node 2

Tags: flash, math, actionscript, html5-canvas, trigonometry

We have node2:

```
x: 300
y: 100
```

we have node1:

```
x: 100;
y: ???
```

so what I want is to put node 1 exactly at 45 degrees by Y position, what I've tried:

```
                            var distance = 100;
                            var someAngle = 135; // 135 - to the left will be in diagonal
            var angle = someAngle * Math.PI / 180; // to radians
            var y = Math.sin(angle) * distance; // moving to it distance
```

but this doesn't work for me, any suggestions?

Comment: To define an angle you need 3 points. Is 45° the angle at the origin between the rays through these two points? Is it, as the answer proposes, the angle at the first point between a horizontal ray and the ray from the first through the second point? Or something completely different?

Comment: Let's see...you have 1 point and an angle: [300,100] and 45 degrees.  To solve the math, you need 2 points (a line segment) and an angle.  If [300,100] is one point, what is the other point on the line? Note: this other point would typically be the "rotation point".  Both [300,100] and [100,???] would be rotated around the rotation point.

Answer (score 0):

If it is exactly 45 degrees, only the distance is needed. The position of `node1` would be

```
x: 300 + distance
y: 100 + distance
```

provided you use a 'right-up' coordinate system. If the coordinate system is 'right-down', the position would be

```
x: 300 - distance
y: 100 + distance
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is almost correct, just missing an anchor point from where the distance at the angle will be calculated:

`var y =`**`node1.y +`**`Math.sin(angle) * distance;`

```
// ie. node2.y = y;
```